# Spring boot sql table relationships

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, relationship

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL database. Within this application, I've implemented the functionality to create bots. Here's a glimpse of my Bot entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "bots")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Bot {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "currentMoney", precision = 19, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal currentMoney;

    @Column(name = "moneyLeftToInvest")
    private BigDecimal moneyLeftToInvest;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "stocks")
    private List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "bot_algorithms", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bot_id"))
    @Column(name = "algorithm_name")
    private List<Algorithms> algorithms;

    @Column(name = "percentageChange")
    private double percentageChange;
}
```

Then there ist another entity named Stock which looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "stocks")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Stock {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bot_id")
    private Long botId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private StockType stockType;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

My objective is to ensure that each time I retrieve information about a bot, the stocks field within the Bot entity automatically queries the Stock Table for the stockId associated with the current bot. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out how to make this functionality work seamlessly. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your "one" side should have defined relationship to "many" like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bot", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
               cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Stock> stocks;
```

Your "many" side should have a defined relationship to "one" like this

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "bot_id")
private Bot bot;
```

Where I assume that your table `stock` in your database has a field `bot_id` that is a reference to the id of your `bot` id primary key field

Also instead of using `FetchType.EAGER`, you can use `.LAZY` instead that is a cheaper operation, but you can still simulate EAGER behavior where you fetch all `stocks` that are related to the `bot` entity

It would look something like this

```
@Repository
public class AppDAOImpl {
// define field for entity manager
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // inject entity manager using constructor injection
    @Autowired
    public AppDAOImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Bot findBotByIdJoinFetch(int theId) {

        // create query
        TypedQuery<Bot> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                                                "select b from Bot b "
                                                    + "JOIN FETCH b.stocks "
                                                    + "where b.id = :data", Bot.class);
        query.setParameter("data", theId);

        // execute query
        Bot bot = query.getSingleResult();

        return bot;
    }
```

After that everything will be loaded in your bot entity and you can then decide what you want to call to get a result, either only bot to be in a variable, or bot and stocks, but with this join fetch bot and stocks will always be loaded.

Bot would be

```
Bot bot = appDAO.findBotByIdJoinFetch(theId);
```

and from that bot you can simply call

```
bot.getStocks();
```

or

```
List<Stocks> stocks = bot.getStocks();
```

Regardless of what you choose the stocks field in the bot entity will always have data that is related to that specific bot.

Comment: Thank you, I have now implemented the AppDAOImpl and added the Annotations for the relationships. My Entities look like before and I can run the application successfully. But if I now want to make a get to a bot I get a exception, which looks like this:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

It sounds like I am now stuck in an endless loop, which then throws an exception.

Comment: If you are getting exceptions, that are unrelated to the title of the question you will need to open a new question with minimal reproducible examples. This question of yours is related to how to set relations between tables and entities.

Answer (score 0):

In the @OneToMany relationship, the default fetch type is LAZY. So, when you retrieve the Bot entity, you won't get the list of Stock data.

To get the List of Stock when you fetch the Bot entity,
Add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in `@OneToMany` annotation.
Like `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`